# disable caching of images

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, caching

i'm building a backend for a questionary. The changes made in the backend are submitted via ajax. Each question can have either one oder no image. Therefore, I created a folder that contains all the question images which are named after the questions id in the database.
Uploading, changing and deleting images works fine in my solution, but I've got a little problem with the caching done by the browser. If I delete an image, it is no more on the server. However, Google Chrome still displays it. Even after reloading the page, it shows the old picture which doesnt't exist anymore. In Firefox, there is the same problem, but it is fixed after reloading. Opera works fine, I didn't try IE.
Of course, Chrome works fine after clearing the browser cache.
Editing anything else like for example the question text works fine in all browsers. It's just the caching of images which is making trouble.

Isn't there any possibility to prevent the browser from caching my images?

Regards

Comment: Append a random number to the image URL. `<img src="image.png?8293734w9">`

Comment: It wouldn't show the image if your HTML/CSS doesn't refer to it. I would start there.

Comment: You can disable it via HTTP headers but it will be applied for all page

Comment: @mayy00, Nope. Headers only apply to the page, not the linked resources. So to use headers to stop caching images you'd have to send them on the image itself. For example, you could serve the image via a PHP page that reads the image and prints out the bytes, and then you can set headers.

Comment: Really, isn't the problem that the page is cached? Because if the image no longer exists on the server, the page shouldn't be referencing it anymore, right? So mayy00 was more right than I first thought, because its not the image being cached that's really the problem; its the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this in your .htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

This will disable caching for the formats that you specify (you can add more if you are using some other image types)

Source: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html